# PMD working inside intellij as an External Tool

Tags: intellij-idea, pmd

I would like to make it so that I can Run a PMD check as an external tool from withing intellij 14.x

The only documentation I can find is old and outdated based on pmd 4.x.  How do I get it working correctly?  Is anyone out there using PMD as an external Tool?  I tried downloading the built in PMD plugin but when I pointed it to my custom_pmd_ruleset.xml it ignored it entirely --> perhaps the plugin is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair bit of research, here's what worked for me:
[image]

And here's the classpath part that's super long and cut off in the image:

```
-cp "C:\Users\nate\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\nate\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;C:\Users\nate\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\pmd\pmd-core\5.3.2\pmd-core-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\nate\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\pmd\pmd-java\5.3.2\pmd-java-5.3.2.jar;C:\Users\nate\.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.1\asm-3.1.jar;C:\Users\nate\.m2\repository\jaxen\jaxen\1.1.1\jaxen-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\nate\.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.48\jcommander-1.48.jar" net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD -R "$ModuleFileDir$\src\test\resources\custom-pmd-rules.xml" -d "$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$/$FileName$"
```

Hopefully that saves someone some time getting it working.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

The command line parser has changed in PMD 5.0.1, but the documentation was never updated unfortunately. These are the changes:

- `args[0]` is now `-dir`
- `args[1]` is now `-format`
- `args[2]` is now `-rulesets`

When you `-format ideaj`, it also needs three more arguments. Those report format specific arguments are now specified with `-property {name}={value}`:

- `args[3]` is now `-property sourcePath`
- `args[4]` is now `-property classAndMethodName`
- `args[5]` is now `-property singleFileName`

The example command line given in the [PMD 4 documentation](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/integrations.html#idea) used parameters:

```
"$FilePath$"              # args[0]
ideaj                     # args[1]
unusedcode,imports        # args[2]
"$Sourcepath$"            # args[3]
$FileClass$.method        # args[4] 
$FileName$                # args[5]
```

Notice that the 4th argument was actually wrong in the documentation, `$FileClass.method` should be `$FileClass$.method`.

So in PMD 5, this is:

```
pmd \
    -dir "$FilePath$" \
    -format ideaj \
    -rulesets "unusedcode,imports" \
    -property sourcePath="$Sourcepath$" \
    -property classAndMethodName="$FileClass$.method" \
    -property singleFileName="$FileName$
```

You can configure IntelliJ like this:

- File > Settings
- Tools > External Tools
- Add a new external tool:

  - Name: PMD (or anything you like)
  - Description: PMD source code analyzer (or anything you like)
  - Options: Synchronize files after execution; Open console
  - Show in: Main menu; Editor menu; Project views; Search results
  - Program: `path/to/pmd-bin-5.8.1/bin/run.sh`
  - Parameters: `pmd -dir "$FilePath$" -format ideaj -rulesets "unusedcode,imports" -property sourcePath="$Sourcepath$" -property classAndMethodName="$FileClass$.method" -property singleFileName="$FileName$`
  - Working Directory: `$ProjectFileDir$`